# EclipseLink @CascadeOnDelete only works sometimes?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two tables, "books" and "bookstores" that both have a @OneToMany reference to the "book_to_bookstore" table which hols the information how many books are in which bookstore.
If either a book or a bookstore is deleted, that information should vanish, too.

Therefore I use the standard JPA CascadeType.ALL and orphanRemoval=true. To make "proper" SQL schemas that also work when accessing it not with Java, I added the EclipseLink specific @CascadeOnDelete annotation, expecting the CASCADE ON DELETE to appear after both FOREIGN KEY statements.

Interestingly though, it only appears after one of them which I just can't explain!

I tried the DDL generation for MySQL and PostgreSQL but both are the same.

Why?

A compileable mini project is here:
svn+ssh://lathspell@svn.code.sf.net/p/lathspellsphp/code/java_test_eclipselink_cascade_bug

The important classes:

```
public class Bookstore implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")

    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bookstoreId", orphanRemoval = true)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<BookToBookstore> bookToBookstoreList;
    ...

public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bookId", orphanRemoval = true)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<BookToBookstore> bookToBookstoreList;
    ...

public class BookToBookstore implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "bookstore_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Bookstore bookstoreId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Book bookId;
    ...
```

The generated SQL for MySQL, note the missing CASCADE ON DELETE in the **last** line:

```
CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))
CREATE TABLE book_to_bookstore (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, book_id INTEGER, bookstore_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id))
CREATE TABLE bookstores (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))
ALTER TABLE book_to_bookstore ADD CONSTRAINT FK_book_to_bookstore_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE book_to_bookstore ADD CONSTRAINT FK_book_to_bookstore_bookstore_id FOREIGN KEY (bookstore_id) REFERENCES bookstores (id)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer or a workaround?

Comment: Found this after noticing the same problem.  It looks like the original poster opened [Bug 416762](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416762) on EclipseLink (with no further updates since).

Comment: I updated that Bug with some info I found stepping through in the debugger (hoping there was a fix that would jump out to a non-expert).   But I did find that there seems to be a HashMap.values() underneath it all.    This at least explains why it works some of the time... (if the ordering is correct).    I wonder if you knew the hash impl well enough, and had a simple set of tables, if you could use this as a workaround by picking just the right names.    That wasn't interesting to me as a workaround though...